# Mirroring SQL error log - Error: 8474, State: 11

Tags: sql-server-2005, mirroring, error-log

I'm getting these errors in SQL error logs:

> An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint,
>   Error: 8474, State: 11. (Near endpoint role: Target, far endpoint address: '')
>   Error: 9642, Severity: 16, State: 3.

Principal and mirror servers are in synchronized state. They have been in synchronized state for some months now, but I keep getting these error messages, I checked the permissions and everything is like its supposed to. Timing on both the servers is the same.

How can I stop these error messages. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mirror state is likely confused at this point and should not be trusted. cherish.j.wang posted the following at: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1237273-1549-1.aspx

```
use master
GO
alter endpoint endpoint_name state = stopped;
GO
alter endpoint endpoint_name state = started;
GO
```

In that same discussion Robert Davis (SQL Soldier) agreed that would resolve the problem for the moment.  But he also pointed out that if you use the fully qualified domain name of the servers you are less likely to run into a name resolution error.

**UPDATE:** When you reset the endpoints, it will take the database offline for the duration of the restart.  However, it will not break the mirror.  The mirroring will stop running when the endpoint is `stopped`, but it will resume once the endpoint is again `started`.

The MSDN article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2490051 suggests.

- Run these commands on the primary
- If it does not resolve the problem, run the commands on the mirror.
- If the database becomes `SUSPENDED` run `ALTER DATABASE <Database Name> SET PARTNER RESUME`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, would there be any issues if I start/stop the endpoints? is there anything I need to watch out for?

Comment: There is low risk in doing this, see updates above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've run the commands on Mirror (I know you said to run them on Primary) as I was getting the errors on the mirrored server. Everything ran well, they came up in less than 10 secs (about 80 databases). I've been trying to a find a solution for the past few days, hopefully this will stop the errors. thanks again.