# Endpoint acting as a mirror and witness?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

Let's say I have 4 SQLServer 2012 R2 divided into two mirrors:

- SQL1-1 with its mirror SQL1-2. The Witness is SQL2-2.
- SQL2-1 with its mirror SQL2-2. The Witness is SQL1-2.

The mirorring has been created with GUI, so I have only one endpoint for mirorring on each server : `TCP://SQLx-x.fqdn.lan:5022` (except built-in endpoints like NamedPipes, etc).

So, for servers SQL1-2 and SQL2-2, this endpoint is used for mirorring AND witnessing of the other mirror. Can this be a problem?

This question came because of an unexpected failover last night and this message in event logs :

> An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport
>   connection endpoint, Error: 8474, State: 11. (Near endpoint role:
>   Target, far endpoint address: '')

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86049/mirroring-sql-error-log-error-8474-state-11) is a solution (restarting endpoints) which didn't worked for me.

Additional informations :

- I can `telnet TCP://SQLx-x.fqdn.lan 5022` from every servers
- Endpoints permissions seems to be fine

Thanks, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Just curious - why would you keep a secondary mirror server of a different mirroring pair as a witness of each other. E.g. Why do you have a witness `SQL2-2` which acts as mirror(secondary) to SQL2-1 ?

Comment: No real reason. The customer installed 4 SQLServ at the beginning, and don't want to change for now. I know, it means more licenses, but..

Comment: You should certainly keep each mirror setup separate.  Create a new mirror endpoint on 1-2 for use by the second group of servers, and one on 2-2 for use by the first group of servers.